# Why algorithm is computational procedure?

Tags: algorithms

I am reading a book: [Introduction to Algorithms](https://www.amazon.in/INTRODUCTION-ALGORITHMS-FOURTH-Charles-Leiserson/dp/026204630X).

In the first chapter is itself, Algorithm is defined as `is any well-defined computational procedure that takes some value, or set of values, as input and produces some value, or set of values, as output in a finite amount of time.`

I am not able to understand the what does computational mean and why procedure has to be computational. I have tried to refer many websites to understand the meaning of computational but I am not able to any get intuition and finding difficulty to grasp the concept.

If someone can explain or share the resources to read , It will be great help.

Comment: You have some input numbers, you do something with them which is usually called a computation, and you return numbers. The abstract form of "numbers in, numbers out" is called a procedure, function or routine depending on context and tradition. You might call the statement redundant

Comment: This is an ill-stated query. I, myself, wonder how much, if any, of it is autogenerated. Would OP kindly elaborate?

Comment: @LutzLehmann und WolfgandBangerth: your hearts are in the right place.

Comment: @ruralreader, I haven't understood your question?

Comment: Welcome to scicomp. In this community we mostly talk about numbers (Integers, floating point numbers etc.), but there are also algorithms dealing with other information such as strings or images. I personaly would extend the word 'computation' also to those entities, but I do understand that someone may find it confusing to call string operations or sorting as "computation". So maybe you just have to extend your interpretation of 'computation' to any 'sequence of actions on sets of information'. hth

Answer (score 6):

"computational procedure" = "a procedure that *computes* something" where "to compute" generally means "a sequence of arithmetic operations". Arithmetic operations are additions, subtractions, multiplications, and divisions of numbers.

Answer (score -1):

After going through lot of article and also taken help of bard. I can conclude below.

`Any procedure that involves Boolean operation(reflects decision making)  or arithmetic operation (addition, subtraction, division or multiplication) at the most fundamental level can be called computational procedure.`

Comment: Down voter, Please help me to understand where I am wrong and what can be corrected.

Comment: I guess providing the references you came across could help.

Comment: This is my own conclusion. What I understand that computation means to yield something on some input on the basis of algorithm(logic of how to yield). The computation involves some basic operation which is arithmetic and boolean operations at the lowest level i.e, when dealing with binary. This is what also any computing device is doing.

Comment: I would really appreciate and may be can't thank enough to someone who finds flaws in my understanding.